# Multi-Select ListBox - Methods Do Not Seem To Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I'm working with C# 2.0 - VS 2005 Latest SP's.

The problem is I cannot capture the second items from the UserGroup box even though the ListBox SelectionMode is set to multiple.  I have attached the button that processes the listbox.  I've included the two segments of code that I've tried to resolve this issue.  That is marked in the comments.

I'm getting the 1st selected item as true, but the second selected item is false.  So the addition of the selected value to the Grp object never happens.

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="UserGroup" Rows="5" runat="server" SelectionMode="multiple" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:ListBox>
```

Code Here:

```
  protected void MapStudentGroup_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstGroup = this.FindControl("UserGroup") as ListBox;
        ListBox lstStudent = this.FindControl("lbStudent") as ListBox;
        List<Group> Grps = new List<Group>();

        if (lstGroup.SelectedIndex != -1 && lstStudent.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            UserGroup usrGrp = new UserGroup();
            usrGrp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(lstStudent.SelectedValue);
            // get selected groups....

            // 1st Method tried here: 
            foreach (ListItem itm in lstGroup.Items)
            {
                if (itm.Selected == true)
                {
                    Group grp = new Group();
                    grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(itm.Value);
                    Grps.Add(grp);
                }
            }

            // 2nd method tried.
            for (int i = 0; i < lstGroup.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (lstGroup.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    Group grp = new Group();
                    grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(lstGroup.Items[i].Value);
                    Grps.Add(grp);
                }
            }

            // 3rd attempt : multiple selected items still not seen - Firefox Issue? 
            List<ListItem> selectedItems = new List<ListItem>();
            int[] selectedItemsIndexes = lstGroup.GetSelectedIndices();
            foreach (int selectedItem in selectedItemsIndexes)
            {
                //selectedItems.Add(lstGroup.Items[selectedItem]);
                Group grp = new Group();
                grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(lstGroup.Items[selectedItem].Value);
                Grps.Add(grp);
            }

            usrGrp.UserGroups = Grps;
            // update group-user mappings...
            usrGrp.UpdateUserGroups(usrGrp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where and what is "lbStudent"? Have you chosen items from two ListBoxes?

Comment: That is a check to verify a student has been selected.  In the database I am making an association between the Student and a Group into a n-m table mapping.

Comment: and in spite of choosing an item, lst.Student.SelectedIndex is -1?

Comment: @Jan-Frederik Carl - well, the two controls Student / Group do not load in relation to each other.   While I could write code to hide items on this page until a student is selected, this is supposed to be a quick/dirty admin page to facilitate mapping many-to-many tables for clients.   Since both list boxes populate from different tables, I was trying to prevent a situation where client had not selected one or the other boxes before attempting to map a pair of items to the many-to-many table.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I would actually simplify things first by doing the following:</strike>

```
    foreach (object itm in lstGroup.SelectedItems)
    {
         Group grp = new Group();
         grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(itm);
         Grps.Add(grp);
    }
```

This way the code is slightly cleaner. Testing this, I am able to get all of my selections to show up.

Since you haven't really mentioned anything about debugging, if the above solution doesn't work for you, I would put a breakpoint immediately after the `foreach` ends and look at the contents of `Grps`.  If `Grps` has the right amount of items in it, then the problem is further down in your code.  Perhaps it is in `usrGrp.UpdateUserGroups()` method.

I don't really see why `Grps` wouldn't have the right number of items in it, but if it doesn't, let us know and I am sure we can figure something out.

**Update**: I tried a stripped down version of your code. It works properly for me. Test this out and then see if you can build it back up to do what you need it to do.

I've defined a simple list to store the selections:

```
List<int> selectionList = new List<int>();
```

Then, I populate it using your general framework, except I call the control directly since it already exists on the current page, rather than relying on this.FindControl().

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem itm in UserGroup.Items)
    {
        if (itm.Selected == true)
        {
            selectionList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(itm.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

After this button is pressed, if I've selected 3 items, then 3 items are in selectionList.  Hopefully, you have the same result. Good luck!

Comment: These are ASP.NET webforms, not windowsforms.  SelectedItems is not defined in Listbox 2.0 or at least that's what I see in my object browser.  Thank you anyways.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: @ericm My apologies about the webforms vs. winforms mistake. What about the second half of my answer?  What are the results of debugging?

Comment: Sorry I did not get back sooner.  I've debugged all three options, and the first one using ListItm only sees the first item selected.  The 2nd piece of code using the Items.Count, only returns the first item selected.  Method 3, again only returns one selected indices.   This was a minor bug for me that I've put on the backburner.  I am going to remove the control from the page and recreate today and retest.

Comment: Thanks for everyone helps.  This one turned out to be a problem with a stored procedure down in the DAL.  The table had been replaced in all but one place.  That old table had multiple values for my id.   thanks for everyones suggesting.  This is a great community.  Much appreciation for your patience.

Comment: @ericm Not a problem. Glad to hear you figured it out. You should post your solution, in some form, as an answer and mark it as answered so this question doesn't persist as unsolved.